# How to change a variable for the whole program

Tags: class, variables, tkinter, command

So I have a program with a Tkinter interface. I used just one class and a few commands but when I change a variable in a command it doesn' t change it for the whole program, but only in the command. How can I make that variable change for the whole program in a command?

Comment: this question is too vague. Can you give us a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` to declare a global variable

```
global myVar
```